# Calculate conditional expectation and variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have to caluclate the following expressions, can sb verify my results, please?

$$E\left(\int_0^2W_t \, dt \mid F_1\right)$$

My result: $\displaystyle\int_0^1W_t \, dt + \frac{5}{2} +W_1$ (corrected)

$$E\left(\int_0^2(4t^2+t) \, dW_t+\int_0^1t^2 \, dt\right)$$

My result: $\dfrac{1}{3}$

$$D^2\left(\int_0^1(t^2+1)\,dW_t\right)$$

My result: $\dfrac{28}{15}$

Comment: 1. No; note that $\mathbb{E}(\dots \mid F_1)$ has to be $F_1$-measurable! 2. Yes. 3. What's $D^2$?

Comment: D^2 - variance. I'll post full answer for 1), im curious where i made mistakes.

Comment: Then the third one is correct.

Comment: of sh...t. in 1. I rewrote my answer incorrectly. It should be $\int_0^1 W_t dt +\frac{5}{2} + W_1$

Comment: Still not correct. Note that both expressions should have the same expectation.

Comment: $E(\int_0^2W_t dt |F_1)=E(\int_0^1 W_t dt |F_1)+E(\int_1^2 W_t dt |F_1)=\int_0^1 W_t dt + E(\int_1^2 (W_t-W_1+W_1)dt |F_1)=\int_0^1 W_t dt+\int_1^2 E(W_t-W_1)dt+ \int_1^2 W_1dt$. Is this wrong?

Comment: So far it is correct.

Comment: $=\int_0^1W_tdt + 0 + W_1$

Comment: But if we take expectation of elft and right side then they are not equal still

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: $E(\int_0^2 W_t dt)\ne E(\int_0^1 W_t dt) $

Comment: Why is that? $0=0$ as far as I know.

Comment: how they are zero? we are integrating with resect to time, they aren't stochastic integrals. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Apply Fubini's theorem and note that $\mathbb{E}(W_t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: oh sh...t. im a stochastic-noob. Thank you for your patience!